# SSH password less login works in one target but not on another

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, openssh

I have generated the ssh keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` in a embedded target (imx6) and copied the public key to host machine.

**Target machine IMX6:**
OpenSSH : 7.1p2
IP: 192.168.2.31

**Host machine:**
OpenSSH: OpenSSH_5.9p1
IP: 192.168.2.11

**Target A to Machine B**
I have tried connecting the host from target and it worked fine. Please find the logs below.

```
mx6q:~# ssh pnallathambi@192.168.2.11 -vv
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.11 [192.168.2.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.2.11:22 as 'pnallathambi'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchan1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbce
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbce
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh6
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh6
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:6hGhaP5vujRRSDEE7e6unEHBXIkPgx9Q6f0U9zvXt1E
debug1: Host '192.168.2.11' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x15e3c28),
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS vmlxhi-025 ssh-pty

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:VaQIZBXXXq8H7m6Um+/hfEllTx3VsgygYZhwUd/i1dY
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.2.11 ([192.168.2.11]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: callback start
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
debug2: fd 4 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-95-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

35 packages can be updated.
35 updates are security updates.


Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2017.

Last login: Fri Sep 23 15:42:05 2016 from 192.168.2.31
pnallathambi@vmlxhi-025:~$ exit
logout
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.2.11 closed.
Transferred: sent 3564, received 3364 bytes, in 2.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1309.0, received 1235.5
debug1: Exit status 0
```

**Target C to Machine D:**
I have copied the same keys to another pair of machines i.e. another target and add the public key to connected host machine. This time it didn't work and I couldn't narrow down the reason.

Please find the logs below.

```
mx6q:/home/root# ssh brinda.mc@192.168.2.11 -vv
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.11 [192.168.2.11] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.2.11:22 as 'brinda.mc'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchan1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbce
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbce
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh6
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh6
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-gex-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group14-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:GAh4JM8Gft7dIgC7nqT+8k5LCpTFJ1hy6t20xQ+hcbc
debug1: Host '192.168.2.11' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x12e5c18),
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS vmlxhi-079 ssh-pty

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Comment: Please share reasons before negative voting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's a bit confusing calling something the target and then connecting from it. And calling one computer the host when they are both hosts, and calling the 'from' computer the host, when while any computer online can be a host, host is often considered to be the one with the server.

Comment: also if you can connect with a password then use the ssh-copyid command after the ssh keygen command.  And it's generally more easily processed english to say connect from A to B, than to say connect to B from A.

Comment: @barlop Thanks. What I meant target here is to specify and embedded target like Beabgle Bone Black. Yes, it's another host machine. ssh-copy-id is not present as part of my RFS, I can try using it once and update you. But my question is "I have same set of topology across many people. Host A is connected to B, I tried to connect B from A with the key generated. I want the same key to be used across other machine pairs also, something like C to D etc., So I tried copying the same key to achieve this. But it didn't work in other machines, it worked only in A to B."

Comment: You could include in your question, a cat of the files that prove that you copied the key over.  Also do an ssh --version or whatever, to show what version you are using 'cos it seems strange that you don't have ssh-copy-id I think ssh-copy-id should come with any openssh though i'm not 100% sure. I guess maybe you are not using openssh. You can also do chmod on the important files to see if you got the permissions right as that's a classic error people make with ssh.

Comment: I see you have openssh.. I've just done `$ ssh -V<ENTER>
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016`    and I have `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: @barlop I will share the files and permissions shortly tomorrow. As am using Embedded Target build from Yocto, these files may be not included in RFS. I will have a check about that also. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build your keys differently if you want one key to work on multiple hosts.

for the way that you built the keys, they are only valid for that user/host combination.  you will be able to go from A to B, A to C, A to D, if you want to, but you won't be able to copy id_rsa from A put it on C, and then expect to ssh from C to D.

they aren't built like that. that's why they are secure.

read the man page again, especially the part about certificates.